# What is the minimal landing area required for an EC135 air medical services helicopter?

Tags: landing, helicopter, emergency-services, netherlands

The Netherlands has a few [Eurocopter EC135](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eurocopter_EC135)s for air medical services. (See [*Wikipedia*](http://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobiel_Medisch_Team#Huidig_gebruik).) How much clear landing space is required (either theoretically, practically or regulatory) for these?

Comment: According to my experience on Flight Simulator X, roughly an area the size of a medium sized town - but I suspect I'm not the most talented helicopter pilot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Theoretically the diameter of the rotor plus some room for the tail is sufficient. If it fits, it fits.

Practically, a bit of room for manoeuvring is required. Also special attention to the generated turbulence is needed in cramped spaces.

Regulatory I don't know the exact size required for the EC135 operated as air ambulance in the Netherlands. But I do know that the Dutch police helicopters are allowed to land on an area with a diameter of 1.5 $\times$ LOA (length over all) during daytime operations. They hit a lamp mast once which resulted in [this investigation](http://onderzoeksraad.nl/uploads/items-docs/521/2008021_PH-RPZ.pdf) (in Dutch - or [English text-only translation](http://translate.google.com/translate?sl=auto&tl=en&js=y&prev=_t&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&u=http://onderzoeksraad.nl/uploads/items-docs/521/2008021_PH-RPZ.pdf&edit-text=)) by the Onderzoeksraad (Dutch Safety Board). Page 5 and 6 show some of the regulations in force at the time (2008).

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I don't think there's a hard and fast rule for this, but it depends on a number of factors:

- Wind/ Weather conditions requiring safety margins.
- Effect of nearby objects/structures. If they are big I think they might cause unpredictable wind effects, again requiring compensation and space.

[image: parkinglot]
<sub>(source: [flugzeug-bild.de](http://www.flugzeug-bild.de/bilder/ec-135-448.jpg))</sub>

That said, I'm no helicopter pilot, so somebody else might be able to give a more detailed answer. YouTube is a pretty decent place to find some tight landings though.

Comment: From what little I understand about helicopter operations, that's basically the deal: You can land anywhere you can fit (the biggest consideration being not smacking the tail rotor into anything). [Various helicopter-related sites offer rules of thumb on landing area size and other considerations](http://www.calstar.org/files/RULE%20OF%20ESSES%20-%20LZ%20Safety%20and%20Preparation%20Guidelines.pdf) (that PDF from CALSTAR recommends 100x100 feet, or about 30x30 meters)

Comment: @voretaq7 that sounds pretty reasonable.